# any software to compute multivariable resultant?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Are there any software to computer resultant for a system of equations (more than 2) with more than 2 variables?

Comment: Fermat should do this http://home.bway.net/lewis/
And I think Magma can too, via either eliminating variables sequentially, or possibly with EliminationIdeal. They have an online calculator, if the problem is not too bulky.

Comment: Junkie, IMHO the question is about multivariate resultant, rather than about how to eliminate variables in general.

Comment: If you mean multivariate polynomial resultant, then the best method is the Dixon Resultant (going back to Bezout).  There is an expository article here:

http://fordham.academia.edu/RobertLewis/Papers

This is for exact symbolic computation.  It probably won't work if there are more than, say, 10 equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maple will do it.

http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/AddOns/view.aspx?path=Algebraic/Resultant

You can also do it in C, or Matlab with MARS:

http://gamma.cs.unc.edu/MARS/

Comment: Maple's docs say it's for resultant of two polynomials with coefficients being algebraic numbers. Looks a bit different from the original question to me.

Comment: Also the polynomials in Maple are univariate, not multivariate

Answer (score 2):

Singular and Macaulay2 do it according to the documentation, though I haven't personally tried using either of them for this purpose.  They are likely to be faster than Maple; I don't know about MARS.